# How to get the first "N" items while using Query Builder?

Tags: sxa, sxa-search

**Environment**: Sitecore 9.3 & SXA 1.9

**Scenario**: I would like to get the first 10 items while using the search query builder. This is the query I am using `+template:{25a72111-ea49-56e0-97ca-3247ffa9a569};sxa:TaggedWithAtLeastOneTagFromCurrentPage|SxaTags;sort:__smallcreateddate[desc]`.

I tried to use the custom tag in the query to get the rows (like this `+custom:rows|10`) but it didn't work. How to achieve this functionality? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try entering a number (eg. 10) in the Page Size parameter while utilizing this component as explained here http://amitkumarmca04.blogspot.com/2020/08/use-of-query-builder-in-sitecore.html

Comment: @RamanGupta This is a custom component (VariantsController), and not extended from SXA Search Results component hence does not contains the Page Size parameter. That's why I would like to make it work using the search query builder.

Comment: You can make your custom component paginable: https://ggullentops.blogspot.com/2018/12/sxa-pagination-on-custom-component.html I can elaborate in an answer if that is an option for you. If that is not an option, please add more information about your non-working custom tag.

Comment: @Gatogordo by custom means trying to insert rows using +custom:rows|10. But as Michael mentioned it is not possible with query builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Query Builder field does not support specifying a page size or offset.

You can write your own code with the Content Search API where you first parse the Query Builder text and then add on the necessary calls to Take, Skip, Select to control what is returned.